# How to compare a dictionary list of items with a normal list in python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a python code contains the string(s) present in **Dictionary List** to be searched in **Normal List**

**Dictionary List:**

```
DList = {}
DList["Key1"] = ["a", "b", "c"]
DList["Key2"] = ["d", "e", "f"]
```

**Normal List:**

```
NList = ["b", "s", "d"]
```

Now, I need to find each and every entry of **DList** in **NList** and if a match found then  should print like

```
string "b" of DList identified in NList
```

and if not exists then

```
string "b" of DList not identified in NList
```

Comment: I have an answer for you, but it is important for the community that you also demonstrate that you are working to solve the issue. Please update you question with what you have tried so far.

Comment: Tbh these types of questions have been asked a thousand times before. But people google such specific use cases like this one that they don't realize this is just a simple comparison between two lists, except one of them is a value inside a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to check all the strings of all the keys of the DList in NList.

```
d_list = {}
d_list["Key1"] = ["a", "b", "c"]
d_list["Key2"] = ["d", "e", "f"]

n_list = ["b", "s", "d"]

d_list_str = set()
for s_list in d_list.values():
    d_list_str.update(s_list)

for s in d_list_str:
    if s in n_list:
        print(f'string "{s}" of DList identified in NList')
    else:
        print(f'string "{s}" of DList not identified in NList')
```

Output:

```
string "c" of DList not identified in NList
string "a" of DList not identified in NList
string "e" of DList not identified in NList
string "f" of DList not identified in NList
string "b" of DList identified in NList
string "d" of DList identified in NList
```

Comment: Thank you Parvez. This fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Based on you question, I think this is what you want. Let me know if it was helpful.

```
for source_list in DList:
    for entry in source_list:
        if entry in NList:
            print('string', entry, 'of DLIst identified in NList')
        else:
            print('string', entry, 'of DList NOT identified in NList')
```

Comment: Hi ddg,
Thanks for the quick reply but based on your code, I will get the Key1 and Key2 in the entry. I am looking for the values comparison. For example, as I mentioned, 'b' and 'd' are the common strings in both Dictionary List and in Normal List. I would get a output like " 'b of DList identified in NList " and " 'd' of DList identified in NList "

Comment: Okay I am now looping through the dictionary.

Comment: @ddg did you mean `source_list in DList.values()`?